# How to access oauth_access_tokens to check if there is a token for the user in rails testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, activemodel

I check there is no model for oauth_access_tokens in rails app but I can use sql to check the tokens. How can I use SQL to check for existence of tokens for specific user. My current solution which is not working is as follow:

```
query = "SELECT user_id FROM table_name"
found = false
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query) do |r|
  if r.user_id == "my_user_id"
    found = true
    break
  end
end
assert found
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query).each do |r|
```